# cvs2svn tool : can we run cvs2svn on live repository. I mean actual repository?

Tags: cvs, cvs2svn

I need to migrate CVS repo to SVN repo. I have cvs2svn installed on CVS server. Can I run cvs2svn tool directly on the CVS repo path which is in live. 
The FAQ in URL "http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/faq.html#oneatatime" says that I need to run on a work on copy of my repositry. Is that I have copy the cvsroot directory path to some/backup_dir and run on backup_dir or I have to run on checkout copy?

**What if I don't want to convert all of my projects at once?**
"Remember to make a backup before starting. Never run cvs2svn on a live CVS repository--always work on a copy of your repository."

Please suggest, i am working on a migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely shouldn't run `cvs2svn` against a "live" repository (i.e., one that might be modified via CVS during the transition). This would utterly confuse `cvs2svn`.

The recommendation is to make a backup and run the conversion against the backup. This recommendation is there (1) so that users don't accidentally run `cvs2svn` against a live repo; (2) to guard against accidents or `cvs2svn` bugs; (3) because sometimes before the conversion it is convenient to move directories around, and this way the user doesn't accidentally mangle his/her main copy; (4) because, this is really valuable data; shouldn't you have a backup anyway?

If you sure that you are too lucky and/or clever to be impacted by any of these issues, feel free to convert from your original copy.

Comment: Clear and Nice answer! Thanks mhagger.

Comment: Clear and Nice answer! Thanks mhagger. just to be clear "The recommendation is to make a backup and run the conversion against the backup."-just backup of cvsroot using /usr/bin/cp to backup/directory is enough or need checkout copy? cvs2svn needs cvsroot path(backup for safe)then it converts files in cvsroot directory. If I have to convert only few/some folder inside project at cvsroot, I can run cvs2svn from any folder in project. If I have understood correctly, I can use normal copy of cvsroot & run cvs2svn, Am I right? i am just trying to understand.